# I can't share folder from my PC with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mount, virtualbox, windows-10

I use Ubuntu 20.04 installed in virtual machine of Oracle VM Virtualbox (6.1.4) and I share a folder from my PC (Windows 10) without problems, this folder is automatically mounted in /media. Recently after a software actualization I accepted to make the actualization to Ubuntu 22.04 and noticed that I can not share the folder. Investigating I made new virtual machines, one with the ISO files, one with Ubuntu 20.04 and another with Ubuntu 22.04.  In the 20.04 there is no problem to share the FOLDER and in the 22.04 continues the problem. Is there a bad function in the new version or there is a different way to share the Folders?

Comment: Please correct your question so I can be sure of what you ask. From your question "In the 22.04 there is no problem to share the FOLDER and in the 22.04 continues the problem." I think one of these should have been 20.04

Comment: The cuestion must say: "In de 20.04 there is no problem to share de FOLDER and in the 22.04 continues the problem"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the "Guest Aditions" CD is mounted.

If the "Guest Aditions" CD is mounted and the problem continues you have to run de shell : autorun.sh

Comment: Question is a bit unclear